# Rigid Body Simulation - solver output window

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I am trying to get my model to run but I soon as I press play it does nothing.

I have attached a model with partial geometry. The inner part is the driver which motors the outerpart about its (outer_part) global z axis.

I have no idea what the solver is doing. Is is possible to display the output for debugging purposes?

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please share your file?

Comment: can't you only keep the object and modify it a bit?

Comment: @moonboots: I have uploaded the model. Hopefully its sufficient to see whats wrong.

Comment: could you please describe what kind of animation you're trying to do? Also what does it give if you copy paste into another Blender (or append into a brand new file)?

Comment: @moonboots: Appending actually worked but then it stopped at default 250. I extended to 1000 but it doesn't seem to solve from 250 onwards. Can I clear the solution and run again at a longer end time/step

Comment: 250 is the limit of the cache, you can extend it the Scene panel > Rigid Body World > Cache > Simulation End

Comment: great. Now its running nicely! Thanks!